How to edit selected words while preserving white spaces and newlines
By word I mean "a string of characters separated by any number of white space or newlines."
Sample data
on a rabbit's burrowing in the forest:
    a short tale

Expected results
On a Rabbit's Burrowing in the Forest:
    A Short Tale

Note: For title casing, the first letter of every word of each phrase/sentence should be capitalized. Every word after that should begin with a capital except the small words a, in, the. I do also want the whitespace and newlines preserved.
Reduced test case
declare -a input
declare -a output

shopt -s extglob

IFS=

read -r -d '' input

for w in "${input[@]}"; do
    if [[ $w = "@(a|in|the)" ]]; then
        output+=( "$w" )
    else
        output+=( "${w@u}" )
    fi
done

echo "${output[@]}"

This preserves white space and newlines, but it only transforms the first "word", whereas I would like all words other than a, in, and the transformed.

Have you checked what $w contains when the loop runs? Or how many times the loop runs? You're asking read to read single NUL-terminated "line", there's nothing there to split the words or make input an array.

please update the question to include sample data and expected results

Also please edit the text of the question to include the question, instead of having the question only in the title.

For text processing, use a text processing utility, not a bash loop. To title-case the first sequence of non-whitespace on a line and all those other than a, the and in, you can use perl:
perl -pe '
  my $count;
  s{\S+}{
    my $word = $&;
    $count++ && $word =~ /^(?:in|a|the)\z/ ? $word : ucfirst($word)
  }ge'

If the input may contain non-ASCII characters and they're UTF-8 encoded, add the -C option.
For example:
$ cat file
on a rabbit's burrowing in the forest:
    a ﬁne short tale

(note the ﬁ (U+FB01 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI) character above, that's not f followed by i)
$ perl -C -pe '...code above...' file
On a Rabbit's Burrowing in the Forest:
    A Fine Short Tale

Which shows how doing a proper ucfirst is not the same thing as converting the first character to uppercase.
If I had to use a shell, I'd rather use zsh:
set -o extendedglob
keep=(in the a)
while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line//(#m)[^[:space:]]##/${keep[(re)$MATCH]-$MATCH[1]:u$MATCH[2,-1]}}
  print -r -- ${line/(#m)[^[:space:]]/$MATCH:u}
done

I find that it's about 14 times as slow as the perl one on my system, and it doesn't handle that ﬁ properly. It does however honour the locale when decoding the input into text and converting to uppercase.
Note that zsh has a title-case operator (${(C)var}), but it would turn foo-BAR-baz into Foo-Bar-Baz not just capitalise the first character of sequences of non-whitespace characters (Foo-BAR-baz here).

I had a feeling you'd volunteer an answer. Thanks Stephane.

If one of the answers here solved your issue, @PoundHash, please take a moment and accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Assumptions:

You want to take a generic text, multi-line and make all except specified words to be upper case. Keeping the newlines and spacing. Assuming singular spaces between words.
As you cannot have multi-line input for your user input read, I assume that you actually will read it in some other way.
I also assume that you have singular spaces between words.

You do anyhow need to update your question to clarify, but this might help you achieve what you want.
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

# Define the multiline input variable
input="Hello this is the question for a specific person
Another line with a and the multiple spaces"

# Initialize output variable
output=""

# Read the input variable line by line
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Split line into words and spaces
    IFS=' ' read -r -a words <<< "$line"

    for word in "${words[@]}"
    do
        if [[ "$word" == @(a|the) ]]
        then
            output+="$word "
        else
            output+="${word^^} "
        fi
    done
    # Add a newline character at the end of each line
    output+=$'\n'
done <<< "$input"

# Print the final output
echo -n "$output"


Thanks Robin. Except for the single spaces between words, your assumptions are correct. I do want to preserve all whitespace and newlines, though. I've updated my question accordingly.
